# What is the bond energy

Tags: bond, energy

$\ce{Cl2}$ bond energy given is as 244.

1/2 $\ce{Cl2}$ will still be 244 or 244/2? My teacher said it is still 244.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). I don't quite understand your question. Do you expect $1/2~\ce{Cl2}$ to be a chemical species?

Comment: What units are you using? 244 by itself doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

The quantity you refer to has units of kJ/mol. Thus, for 1/2 mole of $\ce {\rm Cl}_{2}$, the quantity is halved to 122 kJ/mol. Your teacher might be referring to the quantity on a per-bond basis, but the number you report agrees with references online for a per-mole basis.